# Unable to connect to MySQL RDS through Dbeaver. Getting error message as Connect Timed Out. communication link failure

Tags: mysql

I am getting below error message when trying to connect to MySql RDS from Dbeaver

*"Connect Timed Out.
Communication link failure. The last packet sent
successfully to server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not
received any packets from the server. Connect timed out."*

I am using Dbeaver version 7.3.5

Things I tried but did not work:-

1. Restarted RDS. Restarted Dbeaver.
2. Checked with Firewall team if request is reaching till Firewall but request isn't reaching till there.
3. Tried changing port from 3306 to 3307.